# How to move the camera in three.js?

Tags: three.js

there,how can I move my camera in three.js? I mean than,scene I have a 'road',for instance,I have make a model of many roads in blender and I want to load it in three.js,and I want to move the camera along the road,so what can I do? can you give some simple code? Thank you.

Comment: follow this link http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html

Answer (score 0):

You could set a clock and update the camera's position and lookAt every refresh.

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var increment;

function animate() {
    delta = clock.getDelta();

    increment += delta;

    // moves camera parallel to x axis
    camera.position.x += increment;
    camera.position.y = 100;
    camera.position.z = 200;

    render();
}
```

Or you could [try using TWEEN.js](http://www.createjs.com/TweenJS).